# The connected subsets of $\Bbb{R}$ are convex subsets

Tags: general-topology

What shown below is a reference from "Elementos de Topología General" by Fidel Cassarubias Segura and Ángel Tamariz Mascarúa

> **Definition**
>
> A subset $A$ of $\Bbb{R}$ is convex if for any $a,b\in A$ and for any $x\in\Bbb{R}$ such that $a\le x\le b$ it results that $x\in A$.
>
> **Proposition**
>
> The connected subsets of $\Bbb{R}$ are convex.
>
> *Proof*. If $Y\subseteq\Bbb{R}$ has more than one point and it is not an interval then there must exist $a,b\in Y$ and $c\notin Y$ such that $a<c<b$ and so the sets $A:=Y\cap(-\infty,c)$ and $B:=Y\cap(c,+\infty)$ are two not empty 
>   disjoint open sets in $Y$ such that $A\cup B=Y$ and so $Y$ is disconnected.
>
> So now we suppose that $Y$ is an interval and even we suppose that $Y$ is disconnected. So there must exsist two not empty disjoint open sets $A$ and $B$ of $Y$ such that $A\cup B=Y$. Then without loss of generality we suppose that there exist $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ such that $a<b$ and so we consider $\alpha:=\text{sup}\{x\in\Bbb{R}:[a,x)\cap Y\subseteq A\}$. Clearly it results that $\alpha\le b$ and so, since $Y$ is an interval, $\alpha\in Y$; then by its definition it results that $\alpha\in\text{cl}_Y(A)$ and so, since $A$ is a closed set in $Y$, it results that $\alpha\in A$. Since $A$ is open in $Y$ and since $Y$ is an interval and since $b\in Y\setminus A$ and since $\alpha<b$, there must exist $r>0$ such that $(\alpha-r,\alpha+r)\cap Y\subseteq A$ and so $[a,\alpha+r)\cap Y\subseteq A$, that however is inconsistent with the definition of $\alpha$ and so $Y$ must be connected.

Here for sake of completeness the original text of the proof: I hope mine was a good traslation.

[image]

So I don't understand why $\alpha\in\text{cl}_Y(A)$ and why $[a,\alpha+r)\cap Y\subseteq A$. Then I don't understand why if $A$ is open in $Y$ and if $Y$ is an interval and if $b\in Y\setminus A$ and if $\alpha<b$, there must exist $r>0$ such that $(\alpha-r,\alpha+r)\cap Y\subseteq A$: indeed I only see that since $\alpha\in A$ and since $A$ is open in $Y$ it results that $A$ is a neighborhood of $\alpha$ in $Y$ and so there must exist a basic neighborhood $(\alpha-r,\alpha+r)$ in $\Bbb{R}$ of $\alpha$ such that $(\alpha-r,\alpha+r)\cap Y\subseteq A$.

So could someone explain to me what I don't understand, please?

Comment: "it results that": a better translation is " it follows that", or "we conclude that", e.g.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your advice!!!

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I was thinking that the demonstration proves that any convex set of real numbers is an interval: so to prove the statement of the proposition you need to prove that a subset of R is convex iff is an interval. Anyway recentlyely you showed to me this [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3617022/the-convex-subsets-of-bbbr-are-intervals-or-singletons). Is right what I observed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S=\{x\in\mathbb R\mid[a,x)\cap Y\subset A\}$. Then $\alpha=\sup S$. If $x\in S$, the $[a,x)\subset A$, and therefore there are elements of $A$ arbitrarily close to $x$. Now, take $\varepsilon>0$. Then there is some element $s$ of $S$ in $\left(\alpha-\frac\varepsilon2,\alpha\right]$ and, by the definition of $S$, there is some $a\in A$ such that $a\in\left(s-\frac\varepsilon 2,s\right]$. So, $a\in(s-\varepsilon,s]$ and, in particular, $a\in(s-\varepsilon,s+\varepsilon)$. Since every such interval contains an element of $a$, $s\in\overline A$

I will not answer your other question, since you have provided an answer yourself.

Comment: Okay, so how to prove that $S:=\{x\in\Bbb{R}:[a,x)\cap Y\subseteq A\}$ is a subset of $A$. Then I don't understand why if $(\alpha-r,\alpha+r)\cap Y\subseteq A$ then $[a,\alpha+r)\cap Y\subseteq A$. Could you explain this to me, please?

Comment: Am I sorry. I made a mistake. The set $S$ doesn't have to be a subset of $A$. I've edited my answer. What do you think now?

Comment: The set $S$ is the set $\{x\in\Bbb{R}:[a,x)\cap Y\subseteq A\}$ and not $\{x\in\Bbb{R}:[a,x)\subseteq A\}$ as you wrote: do I make a mistake?

Comment: Not at all. I've edited my answer (again), but this changes nothing.

Comment: Okay, so I summarize. If there exist $b'\in B\subseteq Y$ such that $b'\in[a,x)$ for some $x\in S$ then it results that $b'\in[a,x)\cap Y\subseteq A$, that is inconsistent with $A\cap B=\varnothing$; moreover since $Y$ is an interval and since the intervals are convex sets and since any $x\in S$ is such that $a\le x\le\alpha$ then it results that $S\subseteq Y$; so for any $x\in S$ it results that $[a,x)\subseteq A$ and therefore there are elements of $A$ arbitrarily close to $x$.

Comment: Then for any $ϵ>0$ there exist $x\in S$ such that $\alpha-\frac{\epsilon}2<x\le\alpha$ -indeed $\alpha$ is the sumpremum of $A$- and so there are elements of $A$ arbitrarily close to $x$, that is $(x-\frac{ϵ}2,x+\frac{ϵ}2)\cap A\neq\varnothing$; however since we saw that $\alpha-\frac{ϵ}2<x\le\alpha$ and so $\alpha-ϵ<x-\frac{ϵ}2<\alpha<\alpha+ϵ$, it results that $(x-\frac{ϵ}2,x+\frac{ϵ}2)\subseteq(\alpha-\epsilon,\alpha+\epsilon)$ and so $(\alpha-ϵ,\alpha+ϵ)\cap A\neq\varnothing$, that is $\alpha\in\overline{A}$. Well $\alpha\in\overline{A}\cap Y=\text{cl}_Y(A)$.

Comment: So is it right what I said? Finally could you explain why if $(\alpha-r,\alpha+r)\cap Y\subseteq A$ then $[a,\alpha+r)\cap Y\subseteq A$? Sorry, forgive my insistence.

Comment: Perphaps I understood! First of all we know that there exixt $x\in S$ such that $\alpha-r<x<\alpha+r$ and so there exist $x>\alpha-r$ such that $[a,x)\subseteq A$ and so $\alpha-r\in S$ and so $[a,\alpha-r)\cap Y\subseteq A$; however we know that $[a,\alpha+r)\cap Y=\{[a,x)\cup(\alpha-r,\alpha+r)\}\cap Y\subseteq A$, that is what we wanted. Is it right?

Comment: It looks right to me.

Comment: Okay, thanks too much!!!