# The convex subsets of $\Bbb{R}$ are intervals or singletons

Tags: general-topology

> **Definition** 1
>
> A subset $A$ of $\Bbb{R}$ is convex iff for any $a,b\in A$ and $x\in\Bbb{R}$ such that $a\le x\le b$ it results that $x\in\ A$.
>
> **Definition** 2
>
> A real interval is a set of real numbers lying between two numbers.

Clearly the intervals are convex sets. But how can I conclude that convex sets with more than one point are intervals? It seems to me that it is evident: however I can't explain to me this formally. Could someone help me, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A$ is order convex and non-empty in $\Bbb R$, let $m := \inf A \le M:=\sup A$, where the inf and sup are taken in $\overline{\Bbb R}=[-\infty, +\infty]$.

Then if $m=M$ we must have that $A=\{p\}=[p,p]$ a degenerate interval.
So we can assume $m < M$. If $m < x < M$ we have some $a_0 \in A$ such that $a_0 < x$ (or $x$ would be a larger lowerbound for $A$ than $\inf A$, which cannot be) and we have $a_1 \in A$ with $x < a_1 < M$ (or $x$ would be a smaller upperbound for $A$ than $\sup A$, which cannot be) and then by order convexity of $A$, we have $x \in A$. So $(m,M) \subseteq A$. Clearly, as $m,M$ is a lower resp. upperbound we have that $A \subseteq [m,M]$ so $A=[m,M], [m,M), (m,M), (m,M]$ depending on whether $m,M \in A$ (4 options).

So order convex subsets of $\Bbb R$ are empty, $\Bbb R$, singletons, or real intervals of 4 types.

Answer (score 1):

Hints: Let $m=\inf A$ and $M=\sup A$. (It is possible that $m=-\infty$ and/or $M=\infty$). If $m=M$ then $A$ is a singleton. Now assume that $m<M$.   If $m<x<M$ then there exist $y,z \in A$ such that $m<y<x<z<M$. [This follows from definitions of infimum and supremum]. Hence $x \in A$. It follows that $A$ is an interval with end points $m$ and $M$. The end points may or may not belong to $A$.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand completely your proof. So if $A$ is convex and $y,z\in A$ and $y<x<z$ then $x\in A$. So if $x=ty+(1-t)z$ for some $t\in (0,1)$, then how can I conclude that $A$ is an interval?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro I have proved that all points strictly between $m$ and $M$ belong to $A$. Obviously any number less than $m$ or greater than $M$ cannot  be in $ A$. What does that tell you about $A$?

Comment: Okay. However it seems to me that to prove this it is not necessary to write $x$ as convex combination of $y$ and $z$: indeed for any $y,z\in A$ such that $m<y<z$ and for any $x\in\Bbb{R}$ such that $y<x<z$ we can conclude that $x\in A$, since $A$ is convex; right?

Comment: Well, my definition of a convex set is a set $A$ such that $tx+(1-t)y \in A$ whenever $x,y \in A$ and $0 <t<1$. This is the standard definition. What is your definition ?

Comment: My text says that a subset $A$ of $\Bbb{R}$ is convex iff for any $a,b\in A$ and $x\in\Bbb{R}$ such that $a\le x\le b$ it results that $x\in\ A$. I gave this definition in the question: did't you read it?

Comment: What can you conclude using the definition I gave?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro Sorry, I didn't notice that. There is no need to write $x$ as $tx+(1-t)y$. The main point of the proof is to look at $m$ and $M$.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro your notion is called "order convex", convex alone is more often the linear space/geometric notion. There is in fact a general theory of convexity structures (very much like a topology, but with "convex" instead of "open" as a basic notion), and convexity preserving maps (analogues of continuity), even "separation axioms" for them. There is also "metrically convex", which is studied a lot, also an instance of a convex structure. For subsets of $\Bbb R$ all 3 notions coincide.